# How to add google search results on your site?

Tags: search

Is there any way to add google search results into your site such that the results appear under your domain (and the page doesn't get redirected to google.com)?  I know about [google cse](http://www.google.com/coop/cse/) but this is not a free solution. Is paying for CSE the only way?  Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Use the [Google AJAX Search API](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/) (my emphasis):

> The Google AJAX Search API lets you
>   put Google Search in your web pages
>   with JavaScript. You can embed a
>   simple, dynamic search box and display
>   search results **in your own web pages**
>   or use the results in innovative,
>   programmatic ways.

You just need JavaScript - nothing server-side.

Comment: is there a way to do this so that it is not AJAX? i.e. standard form POST, refresh page, and get results?

Comment: Well, you can POST the data to a page which will have JavaScript which calls AJAX to update the returned page. What does it matter if that page uses AJAX? The user will see a new page of search results, regardless.

Comment: well the page would already have content..so if it didn't post to a new page, I would have to clear the content so that the google results are all that is displayed on the page

Comment: also I figured that if the overall flow of my website is not ajax driven, it would be more natural to simply load a new search result page

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Google Search API](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/).

You could also query Google search engine through a Web Service. [Here](http://api.google.com/GoogleSearch.wsdl)'s the WSDL and [here](http://code.google.com/apis/soapsearch/api_faq.html)'s the FAQ. But I think this will be discontinued in favor of the first suggestion I gave.

Answer (score 0):

What about this? http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/web.html
And there should be even API for PHP etc.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used this but if you're into python check out [Python Library for Google Search](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/python-library-for-google-search/) from Peteris Krumins’ blog.